# How to find what folder process can't open

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, ubuntu-16.04, strace

I have an application that is not functioning, because it can't find or open the folder. But it does not print the folder path.

How i can find out what folders it tries to open or locate?

Probably folder does not exist, or has wrong permission. But to fix this i need to know what folder application is opening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application is using the open or openat system calls under the hood you could use strace to look for any open system call. I would use the following command

`strace -e trace=%file ${YOURAPP}`

For more information you can checkout `man strace`

Comment: Didn't show anything for me. When the app started i've seen dozens of output but when error actually happened strace shown nothing.

Comment: What app are you actually trying to run?

Comment: I've found the issue. That wasn't related to folder, error was misleading.